# How to pass data by button click in redux react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I'm new to `redux`. I have three components are TextField , Button and View. I just stored textfield data in redux configureStore, How to pass data by button click from button component to view component. Im using context how to change in redux.

[Codesandbox link using redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-grass-7fr9bq?file=/src/ViewPage.js)

Here I tired but I want to diplay only when button click.

[CodeSanbox Link using Context](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-snowflake-xpll5l?file=/src/TypoComponent.js)

Comment: In order to use redux correctly you need the store, reducers and actions (thunk for async actions). You will need to dispatch an action on the click handler and handle the action inside a reducer.

Comment: @MirceaMatei i update my question, i tired in redux

Comment: You don't have redux in that CodeSandbox

Comment: No @Micea , Im using

Comment: Add this in the view   const myText = useSelector((state) => state.text)

Comment: Why are you setting input value directly to redux, if you want on btn click?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes i want i just practice myself. could you try this and share me your code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I make ready for you

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Tfield from "./Tfield";
import ButtonSubmit from "./ButtonSubmit";
import TypoValue from "./TyoValue";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { updateValue } from "./features/user";

export default function App() {
  const dataFromRedux = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  console.log(dataFromRedux);

  // useRef to prevent re-rendering
  const inputRef = React.useRef(undefined);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    dispatch(updateValue(inputRef.current.value));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tfield inputRef={inputRef} />
      <ButtonSubmit handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
      <TypoValue />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Tfield.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function Tfield({ inputRef }) {
  console.log("Textfield");

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        inputRef={inputRef} 
        label="Enter Name"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

BtnPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateValue } from "./features/Updater";

export default function BtnPage({handleUpdate}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleUpdate()}> Update </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TFPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { updateValue } from "./features/Updater";

export default function TFPage({myTxt, setMyTxt}) {
  //const myData = useSelector((state) => state.update.value);

 // const [myTxt, setMyTxt] = useState(myData.text);

  //const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (char) => {
    setMyTxt(char);
    //dispatch(updateValue(myTxt));
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   // console.log('useEff - render');
  //   dispatch(updateValue({ text: myTxt }));
  // }, [myTxt]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={myTxt}
        placeholder="Enter Some Text"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

ViewPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function ViewPage() {
  const myData = useSelector((state) => state.update.value);
  console.log(myData);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {myData} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-firefly-kojce6?file=/src/App.js    is working bro but when typing the textfield  it rendering three components also, when typing the textfields do need to render view components .

Comment: @somaiyappan, I edit my answer, please check again, `useRef` will help you to prevent re-rendering, If it works then please accept the answer, also check the `Tfield.js` file.

Comment: @Mihir Shah, please accept the answer if it solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

As per your [Codesandbox link using redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lalande-f88n8d?file=/src/App.js:0-740) Code.

I think you have to change from `import updateValue from "./features/Updater";` to `import { updateValue } from "./features/Updater";`

And it works fine for me

Your current App.js file

```
import "./styles.css";
import TFPage from "./TFPage";
import BtnPage from "./BtnPage";
import ViewPage from "./ViewPage";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import updateValue from "./features/Updater";
import { useState, React } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const myData = useSelector((state) => state.update.value);
  const [myTxt, setMyTxt] = useState(myData.text);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    console.log(myData);
    dispatch(updateValue(myTxt));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TFPage setMyTxt={setMyTxt} myTxt={myTxt} />
      <BtnPage handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
      <ViewPage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your App.js file should look like below

```
import "./styles.css";
import TFPage from "./TFPage";
import BtnPage from "./BtnPage";
import ViewPage from "./ViewPage";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { updateValue } from "./features/Updater";
import { useState, React } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const myData = useSelector((state) => state.update.value);
  const [myTxt, setMyTxt] = useState(myData.text);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    console.log(myData);
    console.log(myTxt);
    dispatch(updateValue(myTxt));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TFPage setMyTxt={setMyTxt} myTxt={myTxt} />
      <BtnPage handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
      <ViewPage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also get a better understanding of the redux toolkit from this given doc [Redux toolkit explaination](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer has the following structure:

```
initialState: { value: { text: "" } }
```

But you are triggering an action like this:

```
dispatch(updateValue("youy text here"));
```

When it should be like this:

```
dispatch(updateValue({ text: "your text here" }));
```